# How to turn a Property<Int> into a SignalProducer<Int, PossibleError>?

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift, reactive-cocoa-5

Given

```
let numberOfSneezes = Property<Int>(0)
```

how do i turn `numberOfSneezes.producer` into this type of producer

```
let sneezeNumberProducer: SignalProducer<Int, PossibleError>
```

?

I know `numberOfSneezes.producer` is not going to send any errors, but i need to assign it to `sneezeNumberProducer` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `promoteError()`. [Here](http://reactivecocoa.io/reactiveswift/docs/latest/Classes/Signal.html#/s:13ReactiveSwift6SignalCAA6Result7NoErrorORs_rlE07promoteF0ACyxAFGAFmF) is the documentation for it.

```
sneezeNumberProducer = numberOfSneezes.producer.promoteError(PossibleError.self)
```